# How can I unset the MAX_ROWS table option on a MyISAM table?

Tags: mysql, database-design, alter

I have a table defined as such:

```
CREATE TABLE `_debug_log` (
  ...
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=896692 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci MAX_ROWS=100000 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;
```

I'd like to drop the MAX_ROWS option as it isn't necessary for this table, but I do need to keep the existing data. Is there a way to unset this table option via an ALTER statement, or will I need to export the data, rebuild the table and then import the data back in? I checked the MySQL docs on MAX_ROWS, but it only says it requires a positive integer value and doesn't say what the default value is or what a value of 0 might do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it is worth:

```
CREATE TABLE `_debug_log` (
id int unsigned primary key auto_increment
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=896692 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci MAX_ROWS=100000 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;

SHOW CREATE TABLE _debug_log;
```

gives:

```
CREATE TABLE `_debug_log` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=896692 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci MAX_ROWS=100000 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
```

then:

```
alter table _debug_log max_rows = 0;

SHOW CREATE TABLE _debug_log;
```

gives:

```
CREATE TABLE `_debug_log` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=896692 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
```

I tried inserting some data before running the `ALTER` and after running the `ALTER` and it did not seem to be affected.

Furthermore, if you create the same table with the same options but exclude the `MAX_ROWS` option, insert the same data and then take a look at the resulting data in `information_schema.tables` the data is pretty much identical (obvious differences aside):

Comment: Thanks for your research on this. It worked as you described on my own system.

Answer (score 0):

Just set it to 0 if you don't want to use that option:

```
ALTER TABLE `_debug_log` MAX_ROWS = 0;
```